# Can't include standard C++ Library files using GCC-G++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, mingw

I am having a problem including standard C++ library files when compiling with G++
Here is the code i have tried to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
  return 0;
}
```

When compiling this i get an error:

```
test.cpp:1:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
#include <iostream>
```

And I can not figure out why...
Any hints would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit: This is the command i am using to compile

> g++ -pedantic -Wall -Wextra  -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test

Edit: This is the log whilst compiling with -v Any suggestions would be great... :)

```
C:\Users\Someone\Desktop>g++ test.cpp -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=g++
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.1/configure --prefix=/mingw --host=mingw32 --build=m
ingw32 --without-pic --enable-shared --enable-static --with-gnu-ld --enable-lto
--enable-libssp --disable-multilib --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran,objc,obj-c++
,ada --disable-sjlj-exceptions --with-dwarf2 --disable-win32-registry --enable-l
ibstdcxx-debug --enable-version-specific-runtime-libs --with-gmp=/usr/src/pkg/gm
p-5.1.2-1-mingw32-src/bld --with-mpc=/usr/src/pkg/mpc-1.0.1-1-mingw32-src/bld --
with-mpfr= --with-system-zlib --with-gnu-as --enable-decimal-float=yes --enable-
libgomp --enable-threads --with-libiconv-prefix=/mingw32 --with-libintl-prefix=/
mingw
Thread model: win32
gcc version 4.8.1 (GCC)
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-v' '-shared-libgcc' '-mtune=generic' '-march=pentiumpro'
 c:/mingw/bin/../libexec/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/cc1plus.exe -quiet -v -iprefix c:\min
gw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/ Test.cpp -quiet -dumpbase Test.cpp -mtune=gener
ic -march=pentiumpro -auxbase Test -version -o C:\Users\Gabriel\AppData\Local\Te
mp\ccJCPwY4.s
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.8.1 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2,
MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c+
+"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c+
+/mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include/c+
+/backward"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/inc
lude/c++"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/inc
lude/c++/mingw32"
ignoring nonexistent directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/inc
lude/c++/backward"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/inclu
de"
ignoring nonexistent directory "i:/p/giaw/mingw/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/inclu
de-fixed"
ignoring duplicate directory "c:/mingw/lib/gcc/../../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../..
/../../mingw32/include"
ignoring duplicate directory "/mingw/include"
#include "..." search starts here:
#include <...> search starts here:
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../include
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/include-fixed
 c:\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/include
End of search list.
GNU C++ (GCC) version 4.8.1 (mingw32)
        compiled by GNU C version 4.8.1, GMP version 5.1.2, MPFR version 3.1.2,
MPC version 1.0.1
GGC heuristics: --param ggc-min-expand=100 --param ggc-min-heapsize=131072
Compiler executable checksum: e3b01b00b6cf2cc1dc95350e55dafc7d
Test.cpp:1:20: fatal error: iostream: No such file or directory
 #include <iostream>
                    ^
compilation terminated.
```

Comment: Win7-64, and this is literally what i am trying to compile, just the include statement, the main method, and return 0

Comment: Win7-64 doesn't come with g++. What version of g++ are you using, Cygwin? MinGW? Other? Is the command run from the DOS prompt, from a batch file, etc?

Comment: Look at this SO entry. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307507/cant-include-standard-c-library-files-using-gcc-g

Comment: MinGW, it is run from an editor called SCITE, but it doesn't work on CMD Prompt either

Comment: Please read this on MinGW search path for include files in Windows.

Comment: I can see all the include files in C:\MinGW\include\c++\3.4.5

Comment: What does `g++ --version` show?

Comment: So, you have checked the include file does exist somewhere, the next things to do would be to explicitly provide that path on the command line eg via a -I argument

Comment: @itwasntpete :  The "1:20" in the error message means 20th character on line 1.  That's basically at the end of line on that first line.  Makes sense to me.

Comment: @KeithSmith :  Your first link comes back here.  Your next comment doesn't even have a link.  Your link-fu is failing you today.

Comment: So what should i do? lol Version is 4.8.1

Comment: Run `g++ -v -Wall -pedantic -std=c++11 -c test.cpp` and show the output log you get from that. Also show what your mingw directory structure looks like. Do a search for the `iostream` file and show where that resides in the mingw directory tree.

Comment: I have edited my original post with the log from -v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by re installing MinGW